php .env with Docker
To add phpdotenv, I am supposed to run the following terminal command:
composer require vlucas/phpdotenv

But I'm not exactly sure which folder I should be running the command.
My folder structure looks like this:
SITE
--> www
   --> css
   --> include
       - database.php
   - index.php
docker-compose.yml
dockerfile

When I run the composer command from the main SITE folder, it creates a folder called Vendor, as well as a composer.json file looks like this:
{
"require": {
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.6"
  }
}

So now the structure looks like this:
SITE
--> www
   --> css
   --> include
       - database.php
   - index.php
--> vendor
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- docker-compose.yml
- dockerfile

So now I can create a .env file within my www folder with the other webfiles, which looks like this:
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_NAME=myDb
DATABASE_USER=user
DATABASE_PASS=test

So in my database.php file, I try to pass the info from my .env file:
<?php
  require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

  $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
  $dotenv->load();   
 
  $dbhost = $_ENV["DATABASE_HOST"];
  $dbname = $_ENV["DATABASE_NAME"];
  $dbuser = $_ENV["DATABASE_USER"];
  $dbpass = $_ENV["DATABASE_PASS"];   

  try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;port=3306;user=$dbuser;pass=$dbpass");
    $dbc->SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Conneciton failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  }  
?>

After doing all of the above, I am getting the below error:
Warning: require(/var/www/html/include/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/include/database.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/include/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/include/database.php on line 2

I tried adjusting the vendor path in the database.php file, but I still get the same error.
I tried running the composer command inside the www folder, but I still get the same error.
What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

What do your volume mounts look like in your docker-compose.yml file?

The error message says you're trying to open your vendor directory inside include, where it is not located. The fix for that is to correct the path in database.php file, but you say you did so and still get the same error message. Do you really mean your code changes are not caught by the PHP interpreter?

I no longer got the error when I moved the Vendor folder, the composer.json and composer.lock into the WWW folder.

Since database.php is in the includes directory you need to go back a level in your require statement to get to the vendor directory, like this:
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

Some notes in no particular order:

It's very hard to maintain your PHP dependencies as individual Docker commands. Why don't you just commit composer.json and (important) composer.lock files and only run composer install from Docker?

You run Composer commands wherever you want the vendor directory to be. PHP doesn't care about such a location, as long as the PHP process has permission to read the directory (and the Composer process has permission to write it). It's typically a bad idea to make the directory public, so don't publish it under your web server document root (I guess it's /SITE/www in your case), but the same can be generally said about most regular PHP code (/SITE/www/include is not a good location). Similarly:

I can create a .env file within my www folder with the other webfiles

You can, but please don't. If you do, anyone will be able to download your database credentials. Create the file anywhere else.

Calling autoload.php from every source file is not wrong but it kind of defeats the convenience of having a class auto-loader. Why don't you call it in your index file?

__DIR__ is the directory of the file where you physically write it, it doesn't have anything to do with your project or document root.

Don't catch exceptions to demote them to regular program output. Doing so you're killing error reporting features. If you don't know what to do with them, the best approach is to do nothing.

Do one thing at a time. First, ensure you can load the library and make it work with your code, then take care of Docker automation.


